# How to disable animation/delay for Gtk::RadioButton,Gtk::CheckButton

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I'am learning gtkmm3(3.22.2)
and i try to get rid of animation/delay on
`Gtk::RadioButton`, `Gtk::CheckButton` if that's possible.

There is no such slow state change for those widgets in  applications on my desktop (Libreoffice etc.) nor in Qt5 for `QCheckBox` etc.

I am using Debian/xfce if that matters

Comment: Welcome, to receive an accurate answer provide what you have tried. Check also this link to have a good idea about how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;)

Comment: You probably want to check your theme (CSS) because the theme dictates button behavior in Gtk3.

Comment: i've tried tons of themes, tricks etc. any link and/or name will be welcomed